# Wait for Async Web Service to return data before Sending to Adapter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an async web service that gets data from a DB. I'm able to return data fine, but what seems to be the problem is that the app is sending the list, which is empty at this time, to the adapter and it then returns a null exception.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        // Create your application here
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HerdDetailsLayout);

        this.GetData();

        List = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.Details);

        this.updateAdapter();

        List.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var listView = sender as ListView;
            Data item = data.List[e.Position];
        };

    }

    private async void GetData(){

        HerdsRESTFulService herdService = new HerdsRESTFulService();

        herds = await herdService.GetAllAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }

    public void updateAdapter()
    {
        adapter = new HerdListAdapter(this, herds);
        RunOnUiThread(() => adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());
        herdList.Adapter = adapter;
    }

....


public async Task<Data> GetAllAsync()
{
    dynamic responseString = await "http://foobar"

            .WithHeader("Authorization", "Bearer numbers")
            .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .GetAsync().ReceiveString();
}
```

How can I wait for a async to finish before putting it into the adapter?

Where error comes up:

```
 public ListAdapter(Activity context, Data data) : base()
 {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data; // Null here because the async didn't finish on time before the adapter was set.
 }
```

Comment: What returns a NullReferenceException? Specifically which code? You need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Apologies, set there above. Thanks :)

Comment: It's not at all clear where you're calling `GetAllAsync` from. You haven't provided the context. Again, please *read* the link I provided you, because you still haven't satisfied the requirements of a [MCVE].

Comment: Okay, thanks, mason. I'm just trying to solve this and learn. Apologies

Comment: You can't `await GetData()` if it is void.

Comment: You should almost never have async void. Please read over [Async Await Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Guys thank you for the input. Sorry if I broke the rules. Just thought I'd put up what would be needed.

Comment: It seems likely in this case that `herds` should be a local variable, not a field or a property. And you should return it from your GetData method, ex: `async Task<List<Herd>> GetData()`

Comment: But you *didn't* put up what would be needed originally. You didn't put enough code to demonstrate the issue. That's why I'm stressing this [MCVE] thing so much. It's important *before* posting a question to make sure you've provided enough data to satisfy the MCVE requirements. You'll get a faster answer, people will be more interested in your question, you're less likely to get downvoted or have your question closed etc. It's great you've improved it, but in the future try to verify you've satisfied the MCVE requirements before posting.

Comment: @mason thanks, I am actually going to read through it tonight and learn it and understand better!

Comment: @SmiffyKmc Great, glad to hear it! You might also find [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) useful.

Comment: @mason I believe I'd find anything helpful at this stage . But thanks, will have a look at that too! You need a blog for all this helpful info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't await void methods so `GetData()` is "fire-and-forget" meaning the execution will be started then the code immediately moves to the next instruction. That is why `updateAdapter()` happens before `GetData()` is complete.

Change it to return task and then await the call:

```
private async Task GetData()
{    
    HerdsRESTFulService herdService = new HerdsRESTFulService();
    herds = await herdService.GetAllAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

and then:

```
....
await this.updateAdapter();
...
```

Maybe even better is to do some work while you are waiting:

```
Task dataTask = this.GetData();
List = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.Details);
await dataTask;
this.updateAdapter();
```

Comment: Thanks, Crowcoder! That makes sense. It's completely down to lack of knowledge but thank you very much!